# Error reading characters of string

Tags: string, operator-overloading, character

I had a problem while trying to equal one string to another, I get this error "Error reading characters of string." in Visual Studio 2015, in the line that i am doing this "student_name=otherStudent.student_name;" and I just don't get it.
could you please help me?

```
Student& Student::operator=(const Student &otherStudent) {
    if (this != &otherStudent)     // Avoid self assignment
    {
        student_name=otherStudent.student_name;
        for (int i = 0; i < grades_size; i++) {
            grades[i] = otherStudent.grades[i];
            subjet_names[i] = otherStudent.subjet_names[i];
        }
        average_grade = otherStudent.average_grade;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Here is the definition of the class if it helps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#define grades_size 6

class Student {
private:
    string student_name; 
    float grades[grades_size];
    string subjet_names[grades_size];
    float average_grade;

public:
    //Constructor
    Student();
    Student(string name);

    //Print status of Student
    void printStudent();

    //Operator Overloads
    Student & operator=(const Student & otherStudent);

};
```